# Responsive div collapsing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a responsive website design I'm working on and I need to figure out how to make three divs collapse based on a media query. Here's what I'm trying to do:

Screen size 1000px or larger:
Three divs centered on the page on the same line where the left div (rotatorLeft) is 25%, middle div (CenterRotator) is 50% and right div (rotatorRight) is 25%.

Screen size less than 1000px:
Three divs still centered but I want the left and right divs (rotatorLeft & rotatorRight) to drop down below the middle div.

The issue I'm running into is figuring out how to make div1 wrap to the next line. The only way I can think of to make this happen is to write some jQuery script to change the order of the div elements in the actual html, but I'd rather not.

Here's the html I have:

```
<div id="rotators">
<div id="rotatorLeft">
<img class="RotatorImage" src="/images/Showcase.png">
</div>
<div id="CenterRotator">
<img class="RotatorImage" src="/images/MainRotator.png">
</div>
<div id="rotatorRight">
<img class="RotatorImage" src="/images/DYK.png">
</div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#rotators {
width: 100%;
margin: 10px auto;
height: 390px;
max-width:1320px;
}

#rotatorLeft {
width: 25%;
float: left;
}

#CenterRotator {
width: 50%;
float: left;
}

#rotatorRight {
width: 25%;
float: left;
}

.RotatorImage {
width: 100%;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This could be difficult to implement because the different layouts imply a different element order in the document. If you wanted to change your design to display the main (50%) div on the left, it would be pretty easy:

```
<div id="rotators">
    <div id="CenterRotator"></div>
    <div id="rotatorLeft"></div>
    <div id="rotatorRight"></div>
</div>

#rotators {margin: 10px auto; }
#rotators > div {height: 200px; float: left; }

#rotatorLeft {width: 25%; background: #eee;  }
#CenterRotator {width: 50%; background: #ddd; }
#rotatorRight {width: 25%; background: #ccc; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    #rotators > div {float: none; width: 100%; }
}
```

If you were absolutely married to the design you could make it happen if you had a fixed height and used absolute positioning.

```
#rotators {margin: 10px auto; position: relative; }
#rotators > div {height: 200px; position: absolute; top: 0; }

#CenterRotator {width: 50%; left: 25%; background: #ddd; }
#rotatorLeft {width: 25%; left: 0; background: #eee;  }
#rotatorRight {width: 25%; left: 75%; background: #ccc; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    #rotators > div {position: static; width: 100%; }
}
```

Comment: I could live with the fixed height solution since these divs will be rotators of images that will all be the same dimensions.  I'll try your suggestion and see what I come up with.